# How to Insert if not exists with multiple index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm setting up PostgreSQL with Flask server and i need to do a conditional insert on data base. Actually i need to check if value already exist on the table, but i want to check multiple record with "AND" operator; Actually i have tried INSERT table(x,x,x,x) on conflict, but it take only unique index in reference. So i need to use WHERE NOT EXISTS like i saw on others Post? I tried this:

```
INSERT INTO table(w,x,y,z)
    SELECT 'ValueW','ValueX','ValueY','ValueZ'
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 'ValueW','ValueX','ValueY','ValueZ' FROM table WHERE w=ValueW AND x=ValueX AND y=ValueY AND z=ValueZ
);
```

Insertion of values doesn't works because of conditions are not good may be ? If someone know a solution, i take it :)

Thx for your time !

Comment: Your code works. I ran the the INSERT... 3 times and had only one row in the table afterwards

Comment: Hum hum i going to try directly in my SQL console and not passing by psycopg2 for execute them, thx for had tried, i conclud the probleme is not the sql syntaxe but what i do with this on my python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are referring to columns called `ValueW` and so on.  I think you want the constants:

```
INSERT INTO table(w, x, y, z)
    SELECT 'ValueW', 'ValueX', 'ValueY', 'ValueZ'
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                      FROM table t
                      WHERE w = 'ValueW' AND
                            x = 'ValueX' AND
                            y = 'ValueY' AND
                            z = 'ValueZ'
                     );
```

A much better method, though, is to declare a unique constraint on the four columns and then only allow updates that follow the constraint:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_w_x_y_z
    unique (w, x, y, z);

insert into table (w, x, y, z)
    select 'ValueW', 'ValueX', 'ValueY', 'ValueZ'
    on conflict on constraint unq_t_w_x_y_z do nothing;
```

Comment: Oh, this reflection method is much better than mine, I implemented it, no more problems! Thx a lot !